# Why is integer conversion done this way?

Tags: c

I ran into an interesting scenario with integer conversion:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned int x = 20;
    unsigned int y = 40;

    printf("%d\n", x - y);
    printf("%d\n", (x - y) / 4);
}

~ % ./a.out
-20
1073741819
```

I wasn't expecting the 2nd result.  Since x and y are both unsigned ints is the result of x - y unsigned (and in this case displayed as signed by printf)?

Comment: "is the result of x - y unsigned" Yes. Try `x - y < 0`

Comment: You can also try `char * p = x - y;` and look carefully at the error message of the compiler when it complains about an invalid conversion.

Comment: The argument corresponding to `%d` should be `int`. To print `unsigned int` use `%u`.

Comment: The first printf could have shown `-2147483628` if you had one's-complement. It's the conversion from unsigned  to signed inside printf that is a problem and implementation defined.

Answer (score 1):

The things you are printing are indeed unsigned integers and you should print them with `%u`, but that does not explain the surprising result for the second number.  The surprising result comes from an overflow occurring when you calculate `x - y`, since the result of that subtraction is negative and thus not representable as an unsigned int.

Unsigned overflow/underflow is not undefined behavior, so it's OK to have code like this in production if you know what you are doing.